# IOS simulator only showing screen, not top or bottom; home button is missing

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Since upgrading to Maverick and the latest XCODE, my IOS simulator is only showing the screen portion of my devices. I don't have a home button. Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

The Retina Versions of the iOS Simulator does not longer have the iPhone frame.

To go to Home use:

Command+shift+H

Answer (score 1):

From iOS Simulator menu choose the following in order to launch the non-retina 3.5" simulator. also in this menu there is the "Home" option which mimics the home button.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

With XCode, in Simulator menu..You can choose between iPhone 5s, 5, 4s and Can change their scale as well If you want to see home button select iPhone 4s and select scale 100%.

Go to 
`iOS Simulator menu -> devices -> Iphone 4s` and

`iOS Simulator menu -> Window -> Scale -> 100%` fro scale